Add Existing Custom Field to a Work Item Type in an Inherited Process
I'm working on automating the customization of work item types in an inherited process using the Azure DevOps REST API. Specifically, I want to add an existing global custom field (e.g., Custom.Name) to a specific work item type (e.g., Feature) within an inherited process.
When I try to add the existing global field to the Feature work item type using the POST /work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields endpoint, I get the following error:
Error: Failed to add field Custom.Name. Status: MethodNotAllowed, Details: {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}}
Class where baseurl is defined:
string baseUrl = $"https://dev.azure.com/{config.Organization}/_apis";
Another class:
        string url = $"{baseUrl}/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields?api-version=7.1-preview.1";
        Console.WriteLine(url);

        Console.WriteLine(fieldReferenceName);

        var data = new
        {
            referenceName = fieldReferenceName,//Ex. Custom.Name
            defaultValue = "", 
            allowGroups = false
        };

        var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


We can not update "core" work item types. To do that, you need to create an inherited work item type: Creates a work item type in the process
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workitemtypes?api-version=7.2-preview.2

{
  "color": "check_and_copy_from_parent",
  "icon": "check_and_copy_from_parent",
  "inheritsFrom": "Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Feature"
}

Then you may customize a new work item type in your process.
